# readxl::read_excel() read excel file path containing Chinese characters returns in utils::unzip(zip_path, list = TRUE)

Tags: r, xlsx, readxl

After setting locale and main path with code below:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale = "chinese")
setwd('D:/lyz用户名/R可视化/')
```

I used `readxl::read_excel()` and `xlsx::read.xlsx()` to read the path of excel file containing Chinese characters respectively, the former returned the error of `Error in utils::unzip(zip_path, list = TRUE)`, while the latter can be parsed correctly.

```
readxl::read_excel("./data/制造业PMI.xlsx", sheet = 'Sheet1')
```

Out:

```
Error in utils::unzip(zip_path, list = TRUE) : 
  zip file 'D:\lyz鏂囦欢\R缁樺浘绀轰緥\data\锟斤拷锟斤拷业锟斤拷锟斤拷锟斤拷业PMI.xlsx' cannot be opened
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="./data/制造业PMI.xlsx": 绯荤粺鎵句笉鍒版寚瀹氱殑鏂囦欢銆?
```

Meanwhile, `xlsx::read.xlsx` could read file correctly.

```
xlsx::read.xlsx("./data/制造业PMI.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1")
```

How can I read and parse paths containing Chinese characters normally by `readxl::read_excel()`? Thanks.

Comment: Problem solved by removing and reinstalling `readxl` package.